# Python:Why invalid syntax here?

Tags: python, syntax

I run that code in python shell 3.3.2, but it gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

```
class Animal(object):
    """Makes cute animals."""
    is_alive = True
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def description(self):
        print self.name #error occurs in that line!
        print self.age

hippo=Animal('2312','321312')
hippo.description()
```

I'm a newbie in python and I don't know how fix that codes. Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`print` is a function in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html), not a keyword as it was in earlier versions. You have to enclose the arguments in parentheses.

```
def description(self):
    print(self.name)
    print(self.age)
```

Answer (score 2):

`print` is a function ([see the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)):

You want:

```
...
def description(self):
    print(self.name)
    print(self.age)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `print` as a statement. It's no longer a statement in Python 3; it's a function now. Just call it as a function and you should be all set.

```
print(self.name)
print(self.age)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 3, `print self.name` is not valid.

It should be

```
print (self.name)
print (self.age)
```